# List python packages installed with pip install <package> --target <someDir>

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I installed python packages at a custom location using pip's option --target. The packages are imported and working fine in my python program which imports the modules. However, when I try to see the modules in my environment using 'pip list', those modules don't show up.
I am using a virtual environment and I ensured that I am in the virtual environment when I issue 'pip list' command